# How to skip where clause without If else in SQL query dynamically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm attempting to write a query but the `WHERE` clause needs to be dynamically applied if search data exists, else skip that part in a single query.

```sql
Declare @search_text varchar(50)='', @start_date datetime, @end_date datetime;

If(@search_text = '')
begin
   select * from Table1 where 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Mydate, 101) BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, @start_date) AND 
   CONVERT(Date,@end_date)
end
else 
 begin 
   select * from Table1 where column1 like '%'+@search_text+'%'
 end
```

I am trying this but it is not working:

```sql
select * from Table1 where  ( Case when ISNULL(@search_text,'') = '' Then CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), MyDate, 101) END   
BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, @start_date) AND CONVERT(Date,@end_date) )
```

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are completely different products; please tag correctly.

Comment: It's for SQL Server. just modified

Comment: Note - your search criteria is not *sargable*, what data type is your *Mydate*?

Comment: Why are you converting a date to `varchar`?

Comment: Why are your date parameters declared as `datetime` when you are obviously and only concerned about the dates? Sloppy code encourages errors. Use an exclusive upper date boundary and you can safely ignore any issues with time in the (presumably) datetime column you reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may combine the logic in a single query, with a single `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE
    @search_text = '' AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Mydate, 101)
        BETWEEN CONVERT(Date, @start_date) AND CONVERT(Date, @end_date) OR
    @search_text <> '' AND column1 LIKE '%' + @search_text + '%';
```